libPNG - Strange error while trying to write to a PNG file
I'm trying to save a PNG file from the content of a Gdiplus::bitmap, by using libPNG. I need the resulting PNG file to be a RGB PNG, without transparency, and as small as possible. I wrote the below code:
void SaveToPNG_libPNG()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Gdiplus::Bitmap> pBitmap(LoadJpgImage(L"..\\SavePNGToFile\\Resources\\IMG_1593.jpg"));

    Gdiplus::Rect       rect(0, 0, pBitmap->GetWidth(), pBitmap->GetHeight());
    Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
    pBitmap->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat24bppRGB, &bitmapData);

    FILE*   pFile;
    errno_t error = _wfopen_s(&pFile, L"..\\SavePNGToFile\\Resources\\IMG_1593_libPNG.png", L"wb");

    if (!pFile)
        return;

    png_structp pPng = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!pPng)
        return;

    png_infop pInfo = png_create_info_struct(pPng);

    if (!pInfo)
    {
        png_destroy_write_struct(&pPng, NULL);
        fclose(pFile);
        pBitmap->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);
        return;
    }

    png_init_io(pPng, pFile);

    // output is 8bit depth, RGB format
    png_set_IHDR
    (
        pPng,
        pInfo,
        pBitmap->GetWidth(),
        pBitmap->GetHeight(),
        8,
        PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB,
        PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
        PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT
    );

    png_write_info(pPng, pInfo);

    // To remove the alpha channel for PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB format,
    // Use png_set_filler().
    png_set_filler(pPng, 0, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);

    for (UINT y = 0; y < pBitmap->GetHeight(); ++y)
    {
        png_const_bytep pRow = (png_const_bytep)bitmapData.Scan0 + ((std::size_t)y * (std::size_t)bitmapData.Stride);

        png_write_row(pPng, pRow);
    }

    png_write_end(pPng, pInfo);

    png_destroy_write_struct(&pPng, &pInfo);

    fclose(pFile);

    pBitmap->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);
}

However this code doesn't work. When the png_write_row(pPng, pRow); line is executed, I get an exception saying:

An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

I cannot figure out what is wrong in this code. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?
